# Save base64 image to Mobile Services SQL or Blob Storage?

Tags: android, azure, ionic-framework, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

So here's the deal, i have an Ionic App and i'm using Azure Mobile Services with JavaScript backend and i need to save images to the cloud.
I have a SQL database (auto-created when i created the Mobile Services) with just one table that'll get some user informations about places and one of these informations is a picture.
I use Cordova camera that returns to me a base64 string to use on the app, but when i save it appears as null on my database (so it's not saving the image).

On the internet i see people talking a bout using a blob storage, using blob storage without mobile services, saving image directly on SQL table, etc.

I want a heads up of what should i do and how should i start be cause i'm really confused and every tutorial is a little bit different from each other. My app is just for demonstration so it'll not have a lot of images going in and out all the time.

If some code of my application is needed, just ask and i'll edit my question.

Thanks.

Comment: Store base64 String in SQLite database with LONG TEXT because base64 string is large.so try to this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a demo app, do it as easy as possible. I'm not familiar with mobile development but maybe put image base64 string into database and then retrieve and render on your mobile, which might be the easiest way to implement.

But if it's a production, I'd recommend to use blob, which provides more benefits than database (especial SQL Database).

1. Blog storage is much cheaper than SQL Database.
2. Support CDN.
3. SQL Server data type length limitation. This might not be a problem if you are just saving users' avatar.
4. More bandwidth. It will not use SQL bandwidth when retrieving image and file.
5. Blob support auto-scale, which could scale-out by container, -up by request frequency.

Hope this helps,

Comment: To add to this, use blob storage, it will be faster and lower cost for blob data. SQL Azure is built for structured data, image blobs tend to bog it down.