# Storing and Retrieving images from Azure Blob Storage + SQL

Tags: android, azure, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage

i've asked this question other day:
[Save base64 image to mobile services SQL or Blob Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901226/save-base64-image-to-mobile-services-sql-or-blob-storage)

And i've decided to use Blob Storage to store the pictures of my application. Searching the web i've seen many tutorials on how to store the image, but not how to retrieve. Be cause of these tutorials i've so many questions, so i'll be leaving what i need to do with my application.

**HERE GOES**

I'm building an app where users can mark places, take pictures of these places and store in the cloud so others peoples can search it and see the discription, images, and everything.

When marking a place the person can take 3 pictures of the place to save it, plus that it have to save the person avatar (so the max pictures one can save is 4, beeing 1 mandatory).

So, when saving i need the text data to be stored at SQL database (that i auto-created with the mobile services) and the pictures (base64) to be saved at the blob with some relation with that place so when a user search for places and want to see that one, the cloud send to the user the data from SQL and the pictures from the Blob that matches the place.

Something like this:
[Saving schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMmiz.png)

And when retrieving i can use the id saved with the data to retrieve the full place.
I'm using JavaScript background, Ionic Framework, Angular and Cordova (the full pack).

Can someone shine me a light?
Thank you

Comment: sorry, what exactly is your question? i think you answered your own question, use the id to retrieve, then use something like `data:image/gif;base64,` as prefix to your src string in your `img`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could have 2 tables in SQL, one for users and one for places, with some properties such as user name, place name, description, etc.

In your blob storage you could have 1 + N containers.

1 containers for users' avatar, which you can use user's id as the blob name. This way you can retrieve his/her avatar directly from blob when logged in (since at that moment you has the user id). I suggest you mark this container as 'public', and render the image for blob's url rather than retrieve to your backend service and send to your app.

You might also need containers for each place, with place id as the container name. Then you can retrieve pictures when a place was selected from this container (container name was the place id).

Hope this helps,